# Android: how to get Context when testing with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm running a junit test in Android which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. I'm using this on order to start up an activity.

The activity uses a subclass of the application object to obtain some parameters. I get the application object from the context.

Unfortunately, ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 does not provide access to the context. Is there a way to access the context *before* getting the activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to inject an Application using [setApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#setApplication%28android.app.Application%29) you should use [ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html), as it is only available in this test case class.

By default, ActivityUnitTestCase, creates a hidden [MockApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockApplication.html) object that is used as the application under test.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way I can start an activity using the ActivityUnitTestCase?

Comment: startActivity [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)]

Comment: ActivityUnitTestCase ist deprecated since API level 24 [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html)

Answer (score 14):

You can get the application context from the instrumentation object:

```
getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: Woohoo! Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those using

```
AndroidTestCase
```

and needing the app application subclass:

```
MyApplication context = (MyApplication) getContext().getApplicationContext();
```